# Prevent Windows 7 users from canceling shutdown (disable shutdown -a)

Tags: windows-7, shutdown, administration

From Windows 7 admin account I've set up a scheduled task with max privileges that executes a .cmd file which executes

```
shutdown -s -f -t 120
```

if the user happens to be logged in and its past their allowed hours.

The user has only user rights but he still can cancel my Admin enforced shutdown by typing in Run box

```
shutdown -a.
```

How do I prevent user from canceling and Admin issued shutdown? UAC is enabled. Thanks.

My final .cmd is this:

`@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%? in ('tasklist /v^| findstr /B /C:"explorer.exe"') do call :USERis %%?
:USERis
echo/%*|find "username">nul 2>&1&&(set "liet=username")
echo/%*|find "Administrator">nul 2>&1&&(set "liet=Administrator")
echo/%liet%
if %liet%==username (
msg /server:localhost * /time:120 "Computer is shutting down in 2 minutes!"
timeout /T 120
shutdown -s -f -t 0 -c "Computer is shutting down!"
) else (
echo Admin logged in!
echo Do nothing
exit
)
exit`

It is scheduled to run repeatedly every 3 minutes during 8 hour period when the PC should be off limits for user. So even if the PC is restarted it still gets a shutdown if User is logged in. Bios has setup password, time & date cannot be changed from user profile. Didn't check if BIOS boot menu works (to boot Linux and change time). Users are Linux dumb though.

Comment: Instead of setting up a scheduled task to run the shutdown command with a time-out period, why don't you create a scheduled task to shut down the computer when you want the computer to shut down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question has 2 different answers. One that directly answers your question, and one that is how you should be setting this up.

### Solution to your question

You cannot prevent a user to abort a shutdown with a timer, but if you change the shutdown to -t 0 (immediate shutdown) it cannot be prevented with a shutdown -a command. You could therefor initiate a 2nd task that runs 2 minutes later that will do a shutdown -s -f -t 0 to shutdown the pc. The user will first see a timer of 2 minutes and even if they abort it, the system will shutdown 2 minutes later.

### How you should solve this

Windows offers Parental Controls with logon hours. Setting this up will log the user out when the logon time has expired. Unlike with your solution, the user cannot simply turn on the pc and/or log back in. If they try to, they'll get a message: logon hours have expired. Wait until you are allowed to login again.

To set this up, do the following:

1. Go to `start` -> `Control Panel`
2. At the top right, Set `View by` to `Category` if this is not already done so.
3. Click on `Set up parental controls for any user`.
4. Click the user that you want to limit.
5. Set Parental Controls to `(x) On, enforce current settings`
6. Click `Time limits`
7. Draw/fill the blocks where the user is not allowed to use the computer. You can use drag/drop from the top left corner to fill in a big area of blocks.
8. Click on <kbd>Ok</kbd> to make this final.

Thats it. The user will be warned prior to being logged off.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know M$ had added something like that :)
Anyways I used both options (my .cmd w/ 0 sec shutdown and parental controls). I'll see how they are doing and then maybe remove one.

Comment: Haven't tested, but it might also be possible to simply change the NTFS permissions on the shutdown command so that non-admins don't have access to the command.

Comment: @MultiverseIT Why would you want to reinvent the wheel if Microsoft already has this feature?

Comment: A user should be able to shutdown the computer manually so changing ntfs permissions permanently wouldn't work. My thought was to rename shutdown.exe right after the 120s shutdown would be initiated and upon restart shutdown.exe.bak could be renamed back. I guess same could be done w/ changing permissions from command line. Didn't go that route though.

Comment: @DebianJunkie still, using Parental Controls is a far better solution. It will only log out that specific user, and on the logon screen is a shutdown button to power down the pc. The shutdown event will notify a user if another user is still logged in.

Comment: @DebianJunkie - As I stated, I haven't tested, but shutdown.exe is not the only way a user can shutdown a machine - I would expect, given 20 years of Windows knowledge, that shutdown.exe is simply ONE WAY a user can shutdown - changing permissions on it likely does not affect the user's ability to go to the start menu and select shutdown.  FEW people would execute shutdown.exe to shutdown a PC.  If this person is amongst those who would, likely, they could bypass your efforts with a little investigation.

Comment: @LPChip7, Who's reinventing the wheel?  There are multiple ways this could be accomplished.  And strictly speaking, changing permissions is the fastest and in my opinion, easiest way to do so.

Comment: @MultiverseIT If it were only to restrict the use of the shutdown command once or perhaps after a certain time, but to recreate all kinds of mechanisms to do what Parental Control does out of the box is in my view reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @LPChip7, Parental controls are meant for PARENTS - not managers.  If this is a home PC, I would be recommending Parental Controls myself.  Odds are this is NOT a home PC.  Please expand upon your solution to indicate how one would use Group Policy or a script to adjust the parental controls on several to thousands of PCs at once.

My solution is easily done via script - a single line batch script in fact using the icacls command on %windir%\system32\shutdown.exe.

Additionally, doesn't setting up parental controls also require signing into a Microsoft account these days?

Comment: @MultiverseIT Windows 7 does not yet work with live accounts, and my answer is totally directed to this question. As for this not being a parent but a company, there is nothing that indicates that it is. If this is a computer in a company, they likely have a domain, and through a domain you can easily setup logon hours as well.

Comment: Whoa, hold your horses guys! The PC is a customer's home PC. IF it were a swarm of company PCs I would most def use my .cmd in AD or samba. Parental controls (ty M$) don't require Live account. The reason I posted this Q up was because I couldn't find a solution from googling. Now I and anyone having such problem have multiple ways to solve it thanks to You:)